# Why do these alternative operator representations exist

Tags: c++

Consider these alternative operator representations: (taken from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_alternative))

```
Primary Alternative
&&      and
&=      and_eq
&       bitand
|       bitor
~       compl
!       not
!=      not_eq
||      or
|=      or_eq
^       xor
^=      xor_eq
```

Why do these alternative operator representations exist? I like them but I am trying to find reasons to give to my manager to allow me to use them.

Comment: Its right there in that page link "To be able to use character encodings where some or all of these symbols do not exist (such as the German DIN 66003)"

Comment: @tomislav-maric But it's perhaps worth pointing out that this motivation is more historical than anything else; DIN 66003 simply isn't used any more (having been replaced with ISO 8859-1 or UTF-8).

Comment: @JamesKanze, cool. I actually like the alternatives, to me they (keywords, not digraphs) seem to be more human readible. I don't use them myself with the main reason them being called alternative in the official doc..

Comment: @Dukeling As he said, he prefers them.  As a C++ programmer, you have to be at least aware of their existence, to avoid writing things like `enum Op { and, or, not };`.  And the editors I use will highlight them as a keyword.  And arguably, `and` is clearer than `||`.

Comment: Then again, `Foo::compl Foo` is not clearer.

Comment: @JamesKanze Maybe you mean `and` is clearer than `&&` or `or` is clearer than `||`???/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As tomislav-maric points out in a comment, the reason is exactly
that given on the page you cite: some older widespread encodings
didn't contain the characters which are replaced.  This is
probably not very relevant today, since those encodings have
pretty much disappeared, being replaced by some of the ISO 8859
encodings or UTF-8.  I don't think you can use this as an
argument for your manager.

On the other hand, at least some C++ experts prefer `and`, `or`
and `not` to `&&`, `||` and `!`.  I'm not one of them, but there
are arguments either way.  My feeling is simply that it's C/C++,
and lots of strange character sequences rule.  (If I were
designing a language from scratch, however...)

With regards to the trigraphs lower down on the page: that can
be considered an experiment that didn't really work.  As far as
I know, no one ever really used them; the resulting code would
be just as unreadable as if the replacement characters were
used.  Consider the alternatives if you were using the German
ISO 646:

```
int arrayÄ 10 Ü;      //  native
int array??( 10 ??);  //  tri-graphs
int array<: 10 :>;    //  digraph
```

Only the last is even slightly readable, but by the time the
last was specified, the problem had pretty much disappeared.

EDIT:

One additional point.  Regardless of personal preferences, you
should make the decision `and`/`or`/`not` vs. `&&`/`||`/`!` at
a team level, and everyone in the team should use the same
conventions.

EDIT:

FWIW: trigraphs were first introduced in C90 (K&R C didn't have
them); digraphs and alternate tokens in C++98 and C99.  (I'm not
sure offhand whether the earlier versions of CFront supported
them or not.)

Answer (score 6):

The C Committee explained why C introduced these alternative operators in `iso646.h` in *C99 Rationale*, I think it can be used for C++ as well, since C++ inherit them from C.

In short, digraphs and trigraphs are introduced in C to solve the problem of using C in the old EBCDIC machines (which support ASCII only partly, so some missing ASCII tokens need to be represented in EBCDIC characters). While the alternative operators are used to keep the use of digraphs and trigraphs to a minimum.

> #### [Rationale for International Standard — Programming Languages — C](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) §MSE.4 *Support for invariant ISO/IEC 646*
>
> The added digraphs were intentionally kept to a minimum. Wherever possible, the Committee
>   instead provided alternate spellings for operators in the form of macros defined in the new
>   header `<iso646.h>`. Alternate spellings are provided for the preprocessing operators `#` and `##` because they cannot be replaced by macro names. Digraphs are also provided for the
>   punctuators `[`, `]`, `{`, and `}` because macro names proved to be a less readable alternative. The Committee recognizes that the solution offered in this header is incomplete and involves a mixture of approaches, but nevertheless believes that it can help make Standard C programs more readable.

For example, the character `|` is not in the old machine, so the trigraph `??!` is used to represent it, but this would make code hard to read is much `||` is used. C solved the problem by letting the alternative operator `or` to be used representing `||`.

Comment: Yes.  For C++, the motive is simply C compatibility.  (At least originally.)